# CSS Table footer with fixed position

Tags: html, css, printing, css-tables

I have put up a simple web page so you can see [a live example](http://xentia.net/test.html)

Very simple table with defined thead,tfoot and tbody. With style definition:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
thead {display: table-header-group; }
tfoot {display: table-footer-group; }
</style>
```

I set header and footer to show in every page when I print. But on the last page, the footer was placed at the end of table, not on the bottom of page (looking in print-preview).

I tried a lot of methods: placing with fixed position, trying to set a fixed size for tbody, but none of them worked.

I need a solution that works at least in IE and Firefox (of course, if it works cross-browser it would be great)

Comment: Thank you Kyle. I move file to another domain, hope it will work now

Answer (score 0):

If you need the footer at a fixed position, you either remove it from the table and place it in a fixed position at the page (altough it may not print correctly depending on the paper size!), but the most important factor here is that you need to have a fixed height for the content.

Understand that the content will push the footer to the bottom, that's why your footer isn't at the base but at the bottom of the content.

BTW, I cant't view your example it failed...

Comment: Thank you jackjoe. I was fix link, moving file to another hosting, hope it will work now. Also - the idea for separating footer in self div element - i try it, but the problem is - you noted - can't set constant height for content. Table is generated dynamically from database and I never know how long it will be

Comment: I have the same problem, and make a div with fixed position is not the solution, for tables than begins at the second page... in this case table footer should be printed from second page forward